# Spring - PersistenceContext - No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa

i am using spring with JPA and all my getters are working. I can get object from database but when i try to save something, i get the error "No transactional EntityManager available" and i have the annotations for transactions.

Here is my DAO:

```
    @Repository("userDao")
    @Transactional
    //public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User, Long> implements IUserDao {
    public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {  

        final protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        public UserDaoImpl() {
        }

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ovdigitalPU")
        protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
        @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void save(User user) throws DuplicatedUserException {
            logger.info("Creating User with username: " + user.getUsername());
            User foundUser = null;
            logger.info("Checking if user already existis...");
            /*foundUser = this.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

            if(foundUser != null) {
                throw new DuplicatedUserException();
            }*/

            entityManager.persist(user);
            logger.info("User " + user.getUsername() + " was been saved with success!");

        }
```

Here is my root-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ovdigitalDS"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ovdigital"
        p:username="ovdigital" p:password="12345">
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ovdigitalDS" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

And my persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="ovdigitalPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
          <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

In debugger mode, when the server try to execute this line - **entityManager.persist(user)**; i get this **exception javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available**.

What i can do to solve my problem?

Comment: Which Transactional annotation are you using ? check your imports it should be spring

Comment: I am using transactions from spring (import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

Comment: But the exception is "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException.: No transactional EntityManager available". Why server is not using transactions from spring?

Comment: Problem solved. I had create some beans with anotations and the component scan is in spring context and data source config is in another context. I had separate it and now it's working :)

Answer (score 3):

It's amazing, but for me the method's signature made all the difference:

```
@Transactional
void save(Entity entity) //throw No transactional EntityManager available
```

and

```
@Transactional
public void save(Entity entity) //ok
```

Comment: because your in your first case its a private method and @Transactional has no affect on non public methods

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and something else solved it for me.

I am using an all-Java configuration (no-xml) and had forgotten the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation on my configuration class. That's it.